# Comparing address string to address

Tags: solidity

I need a function which compares a saved address to an address provided as a parameter of type string.

I tried just to see if I could make that work, I tried the following based on comparison of the hashes:

```
function testFunction2(string memory addressString) public view returns(bool) {
        console.log(addressString);
        console.log(msg.sender);
        bytes32 addressHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender));
        bytes32 addressHash2 = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(addressString));
        console.logBytes32(addressHash);
        console.logBytes32(addressHash2);
        return addressHash == addressHash2;
  }
```

this produces result as follows:

```
0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
0xe9707d0e6171f728f7473c24cc0432a9b07eaaf1efed6a137a4a8c12c79552d9
0x4171dea24ee6cef501949ab6e74eba7924572146d27f2f712aeec3816c71c167
```

So even though console.log in hardhat outputs the same string values, the hashes are different.  I get that some fancy footwork must be going on inside the hardhats console.logBytes32, but wondering if there is some relatively simple way to get this to work as expected (producing the same hash for a string representation of the address, and the address itself.)

Comment: `logBytes32()` prints the actual representation of your value in memory. For `address` that's the same thing you see in an address literal because address literals are just hexadecimal numbers. I.e. `0x1234` is just `0x1234`. For a `string` (or `bytes`), however, you see the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) codes of characters used to write these numbers so `"1234"` is actually stored as `0x31323334` in memory (`"1"` = 0x31, `"2"` = 0x32, `"3"` = 0x33 and so on).

Comment: Converting one to the other is nothing fancy: just go through the string character by character and convert each one to a 4-bit number (i.e. just a value between 0 and 15). Then use [masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)) to put that 4-bit number at the right position in an `address` variable.